# Marshal and UnMarshal Firemonkey iOS Application

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, datasnap

The DbxJsonReflect unit dont work in FM for iOS? I need Marshal and UnMarshal objects. I tried using the FPC routines, but the TJsonObject types are incompatible. Any idea?